# Making a PhoneBook in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads

So i've got two files with the following content:

```
File 1:
  Tom 965432145  
  Bill 932121234

File 2:
  Steve 923432323  
  Tom 933232323
```

and i want to merge them and write the resulting output to a file named 'out.txt'. i wrote this function to deal with duplicates (when the same name appears more than once, it choses what number goes into the final file).

the function is called choosing:

```
choosing :: [String] −> Int −> Int −> Int
choosing ("Name_of_person":_) num1 _ = num1 
choosing _ num1 num2
    | num2 ‘div‘ 100000000 == 2 = num2
    | otherwise = num1
```

and here's what i've managed to do so far according to tips:

i broke the problem into small functions, so it would be easier to solve it.

```
import Text.Printf
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String


choosing _ num1 num2
  | num2 `div` 100000000 == 2 = num2
  | otherwise = num1



parseNameNumber :: Parser (String, Integer)
parseNameNumber = do
spaces
name <- many1 letter
space
number <- fmap read $ many1 digit
return (name, number)

parseFile :: String -> IO ()
parseFile = do
result <- parseFromFile (parseNameNumber `sepBy` newline)
case result of
Left err  -> print err
Right res -> print res


quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
where
    lesser  = filter (< p) xs
    greater = filter (>= p) xs

mergeEntries :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
mergeEntries [] y = y
mergeEntries x [] = x
mergeEntries xl@(x@(xname, xphone):xs) yl@(y@(yname, yphone):ys)
   | xname < yname  = x : mergeEntries xs yl
   | xname == yname = choosing xname x y : mergeEntries xs yl
   | xname > yname  = y : mergeEntries xs yl


serializeEntries :: [(Int, Char)] -> [Char]
serializeEntries entries = concatMap (uncurry $ printf "%s %d\n") entries


main = do
  entries1 <- fmap parseFile $ readFile "in1.txt"
  entries2 <- fmap parseFile $ readFile "in2.txt"
  writeFile "out.txt" $ serializeEntries $ mergeEntries $ quicksort entries1 quicksort entries2
```

Now i think everything is right, except my parse function that returns an IO() instead of a string, how can i change this ?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience @BartekBanachewicz, i've changed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so first off I don't understand the function `choosing`. Could you just explain in plain English how it chooses the numbers? I ask because you have two contradicting definitions there. The first definition that you have says:

```
choosing :: [String] −> Int −> Int −> Int
choosing ("Name_of_person":_) num1 _ = num1 
choosing _ num1 num2
    | num2 ‘div‘ 100000000 == 2 = num2
    | otherwise = num1
```

What this is saying in English is "If the name of the person begins with the literal string `Name_of_person`, always choose the first number. Otherwise, choose the second number if it's in the range 200000000 ... 299999999; if it isn't, choose the first number". That's... bizarre, but maybe there's a good reason.

However, you don't do that when you lay the whole module out. There, what you have is two full definitions of `choosing`, and are effectively saying "Always choose the first number", because that first pattern (`choosing name num1 _`) always matches.

So first, figure out what you want to do with `choosing`. I suspect that what you want to do is comment out that first definition.

Now, as for merging. Are the files sorted by person name? No? Then you'll need to sort the lists once you've read them so that you can identify when there are names that match between the two files. Once the lists are sorted, you will have to do a sorted merge:

```
mergeEntries [] y = y
mergeEntries x [] = x
mergeEntries xl@(x@(xname, xphone):xs) yl@(y@(yname, yphone):ys)
   | xname < yname  = x : mergeEntries xs yl
   | xname == yname = -- You fill in this part, using choosing here
   | xname > yname  = -- You fill in this part
```

Alternately, instead of sorting you could use a better data structure for this than a list (like a `Map`) and use `fromListWith` and `toList`. However, if this is homework that might not be within the parameters of the exercise.

For serializing... I think you'll be okay once you do what you need to do to add all the whitespace in there - remember, a space between the name and the number and a newline after the number.

Comment: sorry, yes the first line of choosing is supposed to be omitted, it is just to choose a number when there's to entries in different files with the same name

Comment: is this a correct implementation of mergeEntries, for what needs to be complete ? `| xname == yname = choosing xname x y : mergeEntries xs yl`  
    `| xname > yname  = y : mergeEntries xs yl`

Comment: Close, but you wanted: `| xname == yname = choosing xname xphone yphone : mergeEntries xs ys` and then also `| xname > yname  = y : mergeEntries xl ys`. The difference between the `xl` and `yl` versus `xs` and `ys` variables is significant and worth considering closely.